# MYSQL View Slowed Down

Tags: mysql, performance, view

I have a mysql view that slowed down when the database it was interpreting became overloaded due to a programming flaw. I fixed that flaw and cleared the database back down to a very small size.

I have a database with identical tables and identical data on the same host/server. It has the same view. The query for that view finishes well under 1sec, but the query of the problem view takes 20+sec.

Is there a cache or something else that I may need to clear to fix this?

---

```
   select 
        `income`.`id` AS `id`
    from
        (`clientsWithIncome`
        left join `income` ON (`income`.`client` = `clientsWithIncome`.`client`))
```

The above is the most simplified form of the query that gives me the problem. I can perform this on one database and get results in under one second, and then on the problem database it takes 20 seconds.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `income` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `index` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_received` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preparer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_began` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_prepared` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_assembled` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_signed` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_fed` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_state` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `highlight` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=93442 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

And the VIEWs:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`xxxxxxxxxxx`@`localhost`
            SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `clientsWithIncome` AS 
  select  `income`.`client` AS `client`
    from  `income`
    where  (`income`.`year` = (year((curdate() + interval 1 month)) - 1))
    union 
  select  `contacts`.`client` AS `client`
    from  `contacts`
    where  (`contacts`.`tax_returns` = 1)$$

delimiter $$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`xxxxxxxxxxxx`@`localhost`
          SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `currentIncome` AS
 select  `income`.`id` AS `id`,
       `income`.`index` AS `index`,
       `clientsWithIncome`.`client` AS `client`,
       `income`.`entity_type` AS `entity_type`,
       `income`.`date_received` AS `date_received`,
       `income`.`preparer` AS `preparer`,
       `income`.`date_began` AS `date_began`,
       `income`.`date_prepared` AS `date_prepared`,
       `income`.`date_assembled` AS `date_assembled`,
       `income`.`date_signed` AS `date_signed`,`income`.`date_fed` AS `date_fed`,
       `income`.`date_state` AS `date_state`,`income`.`notes` AS `notes`,
       `income`.`status` AS `status`,`income`.`year` AS `year`,
       `income`.`highlight` AS `highlight`
    from  (`clientsWithIncome`
            left join  `income`
                 on(((`income`.`client` = `clientsWithIncome`.`client`)
                and  (`income`.`year` = (year((curdate() + interval 1 month)) - 1))))
          )$$
```

Comment: One more piece of information. I just tested and if I change 'left join' to just 'join', I don't have a problem.

Comment: creating indexes on "client" column will improve performance.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant view(s) and table(s).

Comment: I added them. Keep in mind, identical tables and views work fine on another database on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer turned out to be what I thought it was. Some sort of caching.

I performed the following from PHPmyAdmin:

Check table
Repair table
Optimize table
Flush table

Now the queries are performing wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

> `year` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

There is a YEAR datatype; use it.

Add `INDEX(year)`

Add `INDEX(client)`

Add `INDEX(tax_returns)`

If those suggestions don't help enough, come back with...

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the other table.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Use `NOT NULL` on columns that you will always set.